# How to create a new key in Ansible using the ec2_key module?

Tags: ansible

I don't know how to use the ec2_key module in Ansible. Can somebody please give me an example of how to create a new Key-Pair?

Answer (score 10):

working example:

```
- name: Create an EC2 key
  ec2_key:
    name: "mykey"
    region: "eu-west-1"
  register: ec2_key

- name: save private key
  copy:
    content: "{{ ec2_key.key.private_key }}" 
    dest: "./aws-private.pem" 
    mode: 0600
  when: ec2_key.changed
```

Comment: I got an error saying `'dict object' has no attribute 'private_key'`. What might cause this error?

Comment: My ansible version is `2.5.1`.

Comment: `debug` the `ec2_key` result and found if it has `private_key` or not

Comment: The content of `ec2_key` is `{"changed": true, "key": {"fingerprint": "0a:2c:00:1d:c1:2b:cc:3e:e2:3e:94:9e:d3:3d:97:9f", "name": "my_key4"}, "msg": "key pair created"}`. It has no attribute `private_key`.

Comment: problem here is that your key pair is already created. you need to either delete the old one or create the new one with different key name. I have tested the above code and it's working fine

Comment: @ArbabNazar use force: true

Answer (score 6):

The examples in the [Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ec2_key_module.html) appear to show exactly how to do this:

```
# Creates a new ec2 key pair named `example` if not present, returns generated
# private key
- name: example ec2 key
  local_action:
    module: ec2_key
    name: example

# Creates a new ec2 key pair named `example` if not present using provided key
# material
- name: example2 ec2 key
  local_action:
    module: ec2_key
    name: example2
    key_material: 'ssh-rsa AAAAxyz...== me@example.com'
    state: present

# Creates a new ec2 key pair named `example` if not present using provided key
# material
- name: example3 ec2 key
  local_action:
    module: ec2_key
    name: example3
    key_material: "{{ item }}"
  with_file: /path/to/public_key.id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: Is it possible to elaborate a bit what is the purpose of providing as input user's public key in the `key_material` option? When launfing an instance, a `pem` file is created without the console prompting for a public key.

Comment: @pkaramol This is for when you already own a key pair and want to upload its public bit to AWS; as opposed to let AWS create a key pair and send you back the private bit.